# List non-writable files in Linux

Tags: linux

How can I get a list of non-writable files within my current directory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Interpreting that as: user/group/other cannot write

`find . -maxdepth 1 -not -perm /ugo+w`

Answer (score 3):

This `find` will find files that aren't writable by anyone:

```
find . ! -perm /222
```

**EDIT:** From hmont's suggestion on the comment:

```
find . ! -perm /222 -exec ls -l {} +
```

And as Mikey puts on his answer, you can use `-maxdepth 1` to limit the find to a single directory.

Comment: Har! You beat me by 2 seconds, but forgot the 'in the current directory' (along with everybody else). :p

Comment: +1 because it's the clearest one. I would add a `-exec ls -l {} \;` to provide full information about permissions and owner/group stuff.

Comment: @Mikey that can be interpreted in many ways :) But your syntax is more readable than mine on the overall.

Comment: @hmontoliu just to further refine the cmd: instead of "-exec", and since this is linux (vs. solaris et al), you can simply use the faster "-ls" option to find (the format is different, the content is mostly the same): `find . -maxdepth 1 ! -perm /222 -ls`

Answer (score 1):

`find . ! -perm /a+w

find . ! -perm -ug+w`

or some other permutation with symbolic notation to meet your requirements.

To clarify, the '/' will match any user, group, or other.  To match all, precede the mode with '-'.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -le 'print for grep { ! -w } <*>'
```